# JavaScript .bind(this) causes function to lose name property - bug/feature?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my Node JS app, I have a callback that I have to scope to an already instantiated function, traditionally I use `.bind(this)` to register the callback. But if I have a name on the function (which is necessary) the `.name` property is lost and the function only appears as `[Function]` which is incorrect.

The example code is:

```
{
  let http = require('http');
  let server = http.createServer();

  function myRequestListener() {
    console.log(this, this.name); // [Function], ''
  }

  server.on('request', myRequestListener.bind(myFakeClass));
  server.listen(1811);
}
```

Without the `.bind(myFakeClass)` I get the name property as expected.

To see the full code base (My real world problem) You can view the code [here @#38](https://github.com/Tinkster-/coju-router/blob/master/index.js#L38)

Is this a bug within JS/V8 or is this a feature? I can't use `arguments.callee.caller.name` because I'm using Node JS harmony features meaning I run the whole thing in strict. This affects versions of Node `0.11.7 to 0.11.12`

Comment: Is this the case you are referring to? http://jsfiddle.net/QknVL/

Comment: @dystroy Well, it tries to log a static property on the function object and fails, maybe this is the use case the OP is referring to and not the caller.name?

Comment: Voted to close. The solution is not something SO can help with.

Answer (score 2):

You're not logging the name of the function but the name of the context, that is `myFakeClass`.

The name of the function **is** copied when you build a new function using `bind` as can be seen with this simple code (look at the stack trace) :

```
function a(){
   throw "stack"; 
}
a.bind({}).call([]);
```

You can also check that by logging  `arguments.callee.name`.

Here's a fiddle to test : http://jsbin.com/nuresaru/1/edit

I checked it works the same on last Chrome, Firefox, and on node v0.10.26.

---

EDIT : After having seen you fiddle : be careful that you can't change the name of a function by just setting the `name` property.

Comment: Even so, I don't get the name of `'myFakeClass'` through to my callback.

Comment: And does your 'myFakeClass' object have a 'name' property ? Please build a fiddle then.

Comment: yes, all other objects have the name property, as I mentioned above I can't create a useful Fiddle because it's in Node JS (0.11.9 - 10 & 11) I can't use call because that would call the callback immediately.

Comment: I also tested on node v0.10.26. The name is also copied. If you think it doesn't work as the example I give, give more code.

Comment: I'll have a look, re your latest edit; I'm not trying to **change** the name, I just want it's value to register the middleware without having to use an index.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh I've read your last sentence many times, I still can't  make some sense from it. But you must understand you can't set the name like you do in the second line of your fiddle.

Comment: @dystroy `Function.name` is Ecma 6, so you would need to use NodeJS 0.11 with harmony for that to function, right?

Comment: @David I don't know but we're going very far from the initial question there... This now is about the name of the argument and there's no link with `bind`...

Comment: The whole project is to be run with the `--harmony` flag, the question is still about the behaviour of the `.bind()` function and my code illustrates how using `.bind` clears the name in Node 0.11.7+ as my question posed, is it a feature or a bug if some versions do copy the `.name` and some don't it looks to be a bug.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh Did you even read my answer ? Can you spot the difference between `this.name` and `arguments.callee.name` ?

Comment: Yes I did... what relevance is that?

Comment: @DaveMackintosh your  `MyFakeClass` has no name because you were assigning an anonymous function expresion to it. either name your function expression `var myFakeClass = function myFakeClass () {}` or use a declaration `function myFakeClass () {}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set a static `name` property on an anonymous function expression, it will fail:

```
var myFakeClass = function(){}
myFakeClass.name = 'myFakeClass';

console.log(myFakeClass.name); // empty

function myRequestListener() {
    console.log(this, this.name); // [Function], ''
}

server.on('request', myRequestListener.bind(myFakeClass));
```

I’m guessing that this is because `Function.name` is a part of ECMAScript 6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

If this is the case, just use another property name:

```
var myFakeClass = function(){}
myFakeClass.fnName = 'myFakeClass';

function myRequestListener() {
    console.log(this, this.fnName); // [Function], 'myFakeClass'
}
```

Or a named function:

```
function myFakeClass(){}

function myRequestListener() {
    console.log(this, this.name); // [Function], 'myFakeClass'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a new function whenever you use bind().

You may use apply() or call() if you want to change the context of a function (this) and invoke it without creating a new function.

Comment: See my answer : the name **is** copied.